# PHP - file_put_contents is not working

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$number1 = trim(file_get_contents("{$name}.txt"));

$number2 = ($number1++);
file_put_contents("$name.txt", $number2);

echo("$name $ref $number1 $number2");
echo("Thanks for your like ;)");
echo("<a href='$ref'>Back to page you were viewing</a>");
?>
```

file get contents is working properly, since the echo tells that to me, but the problem is the file put contents which doesn't put the content into file. Everything else is fine.

i've set the txt file that the script created to 0777 permissions

Comment: What's with the curly brackets next to $name in file_get_contents? Not sure why it's working in the first place with those brackets.

Comment: well brackets are part of php as i've seen in another post, but those shouldn't be there anyways

Comment: oh and i checked my error log and it's fine

Comment: @itoctopus The curly brackets allow you to easily put a variable within text if any characters around it can be part of a variable name.

Comment: @Deimantas : Tried your code and no error found, file is created and contents added too.

Comment: Try **file_put_contents("123.txt", "123");** to check the permissions and lets verify. @Deimantas

Comment: @SubinThomas, Yep the code worked and the output in the file is 123, btw how many times did you run the code? if you run it twice, it won't work

Comment: @Deimantas : What is your file content??

Comment: the file is created by the script, when i open it, it's 0

Comment: This is the output that i get from the echo deimantas 0 1, as in (file name) (old number) (new number)

Comment: @Deimantas  david_smithe's answer is correct. Try it. Its because of post increment operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number2 = ($number1++);
```

This is a post increment operation, because of that, `$number2` won't get changed until the next increment. So change it to a pre increment below:

```
 $number2 = ++$number1;
```

so the increment will happen directly.

```
/** post increment */
$a = 5;
$b = $a++; // $a= 6; $b = 5;

/** pre increment */
$c = 5;
$d = ++$c; // $c = 6; $d = 6;
```

Comment: well it might be that my current hosting provider has some sort of fishy caching going on then, i'll contact them asap

Comment: @david_smithe : I edited your answer. You are correct in code. But reason is $var++ is a post increment operation, so $number2 is not getting changed.

Comment: @SubinThomas, wrong the number is getting changed as i checked it through echo

Comment: @Deimantas no, you're getting it wrong.
I'll give you an example.
`// let's assume $number1 = 5;`
`$number2 = $number1++; // $number2 will become 5` - it will just get the value of `$number1`, it won't increment and `$number1` only will be incremented, and so on and so fourth`

Comment: @david_smithe actually my method does work, and now my hosting provider has fixed their caching, the script is working properly. Thanks for your help